# Is there a way to find an attachment into a directory with several .msg files?

Tags: powershell, email

I've a directory with fifteen thousand .msg files. These files are named with message_id. So I've a list like this:

...
opec29811_20220601150748_07020_280_1_68@pec_aruba_it
opec29811_20220601225008_20486_905_1_69@pec_aruba_it
opec29811_20220601225011_17147_311_1_62@pec_aruba_it
...

I need to find a message that has in his content a specific string.
For example I want to find the message where the string "IT00513990010_10HK1" is present into the body of the message. Is there a way (maybe using powershell) to do it without opening every single file?

Thanks
Stefano

Comment: you can look into the `outlook.application` COM object.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem path\to\folder\containing\files -Filter *.msg |Select-String IT00513990010_10HK1`